# Add extra node XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2016, for-xml-path

I'm extracting some data using FOR XML PATH. However, I'm not able to get a node. 
Expected result:

```
<Users>
  <User UserId="1">
   <Profile>
     <PersonalDetails>
        <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last1</LastName>
     </PersonalDetails>
     <Reward>0</Reward>
   </Profile>
 </User>
 <User UserId="2">
    <Profile>
      <PersonalDetails>
          <FirstName>Name2</FirstName>
          <LastName>Last2</LastName>
      </PersonalDetails>
      <Reward>0</Reward>
    </Profile>
 </User>
 <User UserId="3">
   <Profile>
      <PersonalDetails>
        <FirstName>Name3</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last3</LastName>
      </PersonalDetails>
      <Reward>0</Reward>
   </Profile>
 </User>
 <User UserId="4">
   <Profile>
    <PersonalDetails>
        <FirstName>Name4</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last4</LastName>
    </PersonalDetails>
    <Reward>0</Reward>
   </Profile>
 </User>
</Users>
```

Let me show you with this example:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE ( ID INT
                 ,FirstName VARCHAR(20)
                 ,LastName VARCHAR(20)
                 ,Reward BIT
                 ) 

INSERT INTO @User (ID, FirstName, LastName, Reward )
VALUES (1, 'Name1', 'Last1', 0)
      ,(2, 'Name2', 'Last2', 0)
      ,(3, 'Name3', 'Last3', 0)
      ,(4, 'Name4', 'Last4', 0)


    SELECT ID AS '@UserId'
            ,( SELECT FirstName AS 'FirstName'
                     ,LastName AS 'LastName'
               FROM @User
               WHERE ID = users.ID
               FOR XML PATH('PersonalDetails'), TYPE)       
           ,Reward AS 'Reward'
    FROM @User AS users
    FOR XML PATH('User'), ROOT('Users'), ELEMENTS
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
 <Users>
<User UserId="1">
   <PersonalDetails>
      <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>
      <LastName>Last1</LastName>
   </PersonalDetails>
   <Reward>0</Reward>
</User>
</User>
   <User UserId="2">
     <PersonalDetails>
       <FirstName>Name2</FirstName>
       <LastName>Last2</LastName>
     </PersonalDetails>
     <Reward>0</Reward>
   </User>
   <User UserId="3">
      <PersonalDetails>
         <FirstName>Name3</FirstName>
         <LastName>Last3</LastName>
      </PersonalDetails>
      <Reward>0</Reward>
   </User>
   <User UserId="4">
     <PersonalDetails>
       <FirstName>Name4</FirstName>
       <LastName>Last4</LastName>
     </PersonalDetails>
     <Reward>0</Reward>
   </User>
 </Users>
```

I'm not able to add that extra Profile element.
I've tried using the modify('insert   as first into (/Users/User)[1]') but the output is not as expeted either.
Can you help me with this please?

Comment: This is a very good question! *Stand-alone* test scenario, clear question, own attempt, wrong and expected output. Great, voted it up!

Comment: I appreciate that @Shnugo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be plain `1:1` internally: nested, but not `1:n`. This does not need a subselect. With `FOR XML PATH` you can specify your nestings directly:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE ( ID INT
                 ,FirstName VARCHAR(20)
                 ,LastName VARCHAR(20)
                 ,Reward BIT
                 ) 

INSERT INTO @User (ID, FirstName, LastName, Reward )
VALUES (1, 'Name1', 'Last1', 0)
      ,(2, 'Name2', 'Last2', 0);

SELECT ID AS [@UserId]
      ,FirstName AS [Profile/PersonalDetails/FirstName]  
      ,LastName AS [Profile/PersonalDetails/LastName]  
      ,Reward AS [Profile/Reward]
FROM @User AS u
FOR XML PATH('User'),ROOT('Users')
```

The result

```
<Users>
  <User UserId="1">
    <Profile>
      <PersonalDetails>
        <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last1</LastName>
      </PersonalDetails>
      <Reward>0</Reward>
    </Profile>
  </User>
  <User UserId="2">
    <Profile>
      <PersonalDetails>
        <FirstName>Name2</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last2</LastName>
      </PersonalDetails>
      <Reward>0</Reward>
    </Profile>
  </User>
</Users>
```